# akka.dispatch.Future not found

Tags: sbt, akka, dependency-management, future

I am trying to `import akka.dispatch.Future` in my class but the compiler is unable to find that particular package. The one that it's able to find is `akka.dispatch.Futures`.

Can somebody point out what I might be doing wrong? My build.sbt is as follows:

```
name := "SomeApp"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.10.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq("com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.1.2")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all in the docs: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.2/project/migration-guide-2.0.x-2.1.x.html

See the "Pieces Moved to Scala Standard Library" section.